# i want to make the div show after few seconds automatically

Tags: javascript, popup, dialog

I need to make a div with a message pop up after few seconds to load window, maybe about 5 seconds.

I was looking for some sources through google, and found a great example in this [site](http://www.queness.com/post/1696/create-a-beautiful-looking-custom-dialog-box-with-jquery-and-css3)
but, in this source, one thing that it doesn't support is to be able to set time. 
In the comments, one user questioned about setting time and the creator suggested something like this

> var show = setTimeout("popup()", 3000);

but it doesn't work for me!

Of course, I asked the same question, but didn't get answers for now.

Here, I'll link to a [page](http://xn--mkro5kr2lovb719a7espng.com/) that I'm working on. Sorry it's in Japanese!
You can find a red popup box that I'm trying to show up after seconds.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    // if user clicked on button, the overlay layer or the dialogbox, close the dialog  
    $('a.btn-ok, #dialog-overlay, #dialog-box').click(function () {     
        $('#dialog-overlay, #dialog-box').hide();       
        return false;
    });

    // if user resize the window, call the same function again
    // to make sure the overlay fills the screen and dialogbox aligned to center    
    $(window).resize(function () {

        //only do it if the dialog box is not hidden
        if (!$('#dialog-box').is(':hidden')) popup();       
    }); 


});

//Popup dialog
function popup(message) {

    // get the screen height and width  
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();  
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    // calculate the values for center alignment
    var dialogTop =  (maskHeight/3) - ($('#dialog-box').height());  
    var dialogLeft = (maskWidth/2) - ($('#dialog-box').width()/2); 

    // assign values to the overlay and dialog box
    $('#dialog-overlay').css({height:maskHeight, width:maskWidth}).show();
    $('#dialog-box').css({top:dialogTop, left:dialogLeft}).show();

    // display the message
    $('#dialog-message').html(message);
}
</script>

<body<?php if(is_home()): ?> onload="popup('<p>「千葉県　行政書士」などの<br />&nbsp;Yahoo! 検索で上位表示している、このウェブサイトを、<br />&nbsp;あなたのものにしませんか?</p>')"<?php endif; ?>>
<div id="dialog-overlay"></div>
    <div id="dialog-box">
        <div class="dialog-content">
            <div id="arrows"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/dilog-box_arrow.png" alt="" ></div>
            <div id="dialog-message"></div>
            <div class="al_c"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/sales/" target="_self"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/dialog-box_btn_off.png" class="btn" alt="HPレンタルの詳細ページへ" /></a></div>
            <a href="#" class="button">閉じる</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't apologize for the Japanese! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    // if user clicked on button, the overlay layer or the dialogbox, close the dialog  
    $('a.btn-ok, #dialog-overlay, #dialog-box').click(function () {     
        $('#dialog-overlay, #dialog-box').hide();       
        return false;
    });

    // if user resize the window, call the same function again
    // to make sure the overlay fills the screen and dialogbox aligned to center    
    $(window).resize(function () {

        //only do it if the dialog box is not hidden
        if (!$('#dialog-box').is(':hidden')) popup();       
    }); 


});

//Popup dialog
function popup(message) {

    // get the screen height and width  
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();  
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    // calculate the values for center alignment
    var dialogTop =  (maskHeight/3) - ($('#dialog-box').height());  
    var dialogLeft = (maskWidth/2) - ($('#dialog-box').width()/2); 

    // assign values to the overlay and dialog box
    $('#dialog-overlay').css({height:maskHeight, width:maskWidth}).show();
    $('#dialog-box').css({top:dialogTop, left:dialogLeft}).show();

    // display the message
    $('#dialog-message').html(message);
}
</script>

<body>
 <div id="dialog-overlay"></div>
  <div id="dialog-box">
      <div class="dialog-content">
          <div id="arrows"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/dilog-box_arrow.png" alt="" ></div>
          <div id="dialog-message"></div>
          <div class="al_c"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/sales/" target="_self"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/dialog-box_btn_off.png" class="btn" alt="HPレンタルの詳細ページへ" /></a></div>
          <a href="#" class="button">閉じる</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php if(is_home()) { ?>
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      popup('<p>「千葉県　行政書士」などの<br />&nbsp;Yahoo! 検索で上位表示している、このウェブサイトを、<br />&nbsp;あなたのものにしませんか?</p>');
    }, 5000);
  };
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Note the code after last `</div>`. By checking the condition and when the condition is true, create a script with `window.onload` with setTimeout inside, then use a anonymous function to call the `popup()` function.

Using an anonymous function into setTimeout is more secure than using quotation mark, because if there has an variable into quotation mark, this will be a secure risk. Example:

```
setTimeout("popup(" + a + )", 1000);
```

If I define the variable `a` like this:

```
a = '"something that will popup"); maliciousFunction(';
```

then the browser are going to call 2 function (your function and a malicious function).

Comment: You should also mention that you wrapped the `popup` call in an anonymous function. It is a useful thing to know!

Comment: @mrtsherman Oh, I forgot to mention it.. That's because the `popup` function has a argument, and this way is more secure to do it than let javascript engine interpret the code between quotation mark. Anyway, thank you for point it out.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    window.setTimeout('popup()', 5000);
});
```